# Superconductor Magnetic Field Limit

Tags: electromagnetism

Not sure if this is a question for the engineering or physics stack exchange:

The current maximum magnetic field for a nonpulsed magnetic field is around 45 Tesla while pulsed is around 100 Tesla. I'm assuming the primary reason for the limitation is that the coils overheat (from additional current being added) but how come superconductors also seem to have this limitation if they have no resistance and therefore emit no heat? Thanks!

Comment: Is Tesla a measure of frequency?

Comment: @Solar Mike It’s actually a measure of magnetic field strength, or magnetic flux density

Comment: So how often is it pulsed from 45 to 100? As you poorly phrased that part… once a month? A week or 10 times a second ie 10Hz?

Comment: @Solar Mike Apologies, I meant the highest magnetic field generated for a constant time without a need to shut it down is around 45 Tesla whilst the record for a pulsed magnetic field where it can reach that magnetic field but only for a fraction of a second before overheating is 100 Tesla, it can only be held for a couple hundred milliseconds and can be fired up again after it cools down (possibly a few ours). The limitation of pulsed magnetic system is the large current causes the solenoid to overheat. What limits a superconductor from achieving higher magnetic fields without emitting heat

Answer (score 1):

Superconductors stop superconducting when they are in a magnetic field stronger than their [critical field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_field) or if their current density exceeds their [critical current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconductivity#Elementary_properties_of_superconductors).  The 45 Tesla fields you refer to [were originally generated](https://nationalmaglab.org/about-the-maglab/around-the-lab/maglab-dictionary/hybrid-magnet/) with a 31 MW, 33.6 T resistive magnet inside a 11.4 T low-temperature superconductor coil, and [more recently](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-019-1293-1) with a 14.4 T [high-temperature superconductor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-temperature_superconductivity) coil inside a 31.1-tesla resistive magnet.
The [record field for a pure superconducting magnet](https://doi.org/10.1088/1361-6668/ab714e), is 32 T for two high-temperature superconducting coils inside an outer low temperature superconducting coil.

At temperatures approaching 0 K, the critical field of a low-temperature superconductor such as [Niobium–tin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niobium%E2%80%93tin) can be as high as 30 T, and can be [140 T](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00724550) or [even more](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physb.2004.01.098) in ideal YBCO single crystals, but these are not achievable in practical coils.

The challenges are that superconductors in higher magnetic fields have lower transition temperatures and critical currents, and critical currents can be [much lower at grain boundaries](https://doi.org/10.1186/s11671-015-1124-8) than inside a single crystal. If the current density exceeds the critical current density at any point inside the superconducting coil, that point becomes a normal resistive conductor and starts to heat up neighbouring material causing it to also lose superconductivity, causing a cascade known as a ["quench"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconducting_magnet#Magnet_quench).  This can destroy the magnetic if not carefully managed.